# What is the best/safest way to quickly dry the bottom of this wall before caulking?

Tags: waterproofing, caulk

**Context:**
During the last rainstorm we had a LOT of water flow into our house. When it stopped raining I quickly figured out why. The caulking between my log home and the foundation had cracked pretty badly and was letting water run under the logs into the house.

The grade is (barely) away from the house, so it isn't normally a problem, but in this story the wind was driving the rain directly against this wall. So we had about a 1/2 stream across our living room floor.

I'd like to get this re-caulked because more rain is in the forecast later this week. The weather is pretty dry today, but it is still soggy under that log and I don't want to trap that moisture in where it will rot the log. Normally I would just wait it out and let it dry thoroughly, but I'd really like to get this done before the next storm comes through and floods things again. Also, it is a shady spot, it is pretty humid out, and the log isn't entirely flush with the ground, so there is some very shady/cool airspace below the log.

**What I am thinking of trying**
I'm thinking a heat gun or a hair-dryer, but I am a little worried about damaging the wood or striping the oil based sealant off of the logs in the process.

Also, part of me is wondering if I shouldn't finds some other way to temporarily water-proof along the foundation until it will dry out, but that would slow the drying process.

**The Question**
Would it be safe to dry this out with a heat gun? Should I just use a hair dryer to keep the temps in a safe range? Is there a better answer? Or maybe the best course is to just let it dry naturally and try to keep the rain off this wall?

**Photo**
Attached is a pic with the caulk mostly scraped out. It wasn't quite THAT bad before.
That said, the problematic section is maybe 15' long.

[image: Caulk line under home]

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use a hair dryer just a fan will be better you don’t want to heat the log in a spot like that and damage the finish.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you get some wide flat metal flashing (height of log plus a couple of inches) and tack it at the next seam up. The flashing will be out on a bit of an angle, and will stop a lot of water from flowing down to the foundation/log joint.

Now you can let everything dry naturally and caulk from the outside at your convenience. I'd lean toward a product that advertises extra 'stretch'.